# splitting data into multiple tabs that already exist

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to split some data based on tab names that already exist in the workbook.

For example I have a worksheet with a list of account numbers with multiple transactions. Next to this I have a worksheet for each account number which is empty.
Instead of copying and pasting the records which match every time I would like to create a macro.

I found the below code but this actually creates the multiple tabs. I'm pretty new to VBA. Is there a way of adapting this code to not create the tabs.. just to populate them.

Help much appreciated.

```
Sub parse_data()
 Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1  

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")       
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"           
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

       For i = 2 To lr
      On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If

ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
```

End Sub

Comment: It really helps people help you if you copy/paste the code straight from VBE into the question - it looks like you have split some lines into two to make them fit the width of the screen, but that of course makes the code give syntax errors.

Comment: It would also help us help you if you told us **what** errors you are getting, and where - we then don't have to look at every character in your code wondering whether it might be the one that is causing you to say "i keep getting errors".

Comment: Also - do yourself and us a favour and indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult without an example or explanation of what the data is that you are trying to sort, but the basics seem to be that you have data sorted in rows in Sheet 1 that you wish to split into several other sheets depending on the value/s of that data.

Below is a simple example of how you could achieve this, but you would have to adopt for the specific data and rules for which you are trying to sort.

```
Sub Sort_Data(Has_Header As Boolean)
  Dim Ws As Worksheet, New_Sht As Worksheet
  Dim X As Integer, Cur_Row As Integer, Start_Row As Integer
  Dim Shts() As Integer
  ReDim Shts(1 to (Sheets.Count-1)) As Integer
  For X = 1 to (Sheets.Count-1))
    Shts(X) = 1
    If Has_Header = True the Shts(X) = 2
  Next X
  Set Ws = Sheets(1)
  Start_Row = 1
  If Has_Header = True then Start_Row = 2
  For Cur_Row = Start_Row to Ws.Rows.Count
    If Ws.Range("A1").Value = "" Then Exit For 'This checks for an empty row and quits the process once reaching one.
    X = 0
    Select Case Ws.Range(Cells(Cur_Row, 2).Address).Value 'This assumes the data you wish to sort by is in Column B (2).
      Case "Value 1":
        X = 2
      Case "Value 2":
        X = 3
      Case "Value 3":
        X = 4
    End Select
    If X <> 0 Then
      Set New_Sht = Sheets(X)
      Ws.Sheets.Range("A" & Cur_Row).EntireRow.Copy
      New_Sht.Range("A" & Shts(X-1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      Shts(X-1) = Shts(X-1) + 1
    End If
  Next Cur_Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Aserc. Apologies for the misleading post. I have added more detail to my problem.

Comment: So the above should work fine for your case then...just adjust the number 2 in the line "Select Case Ws.Range(Cells(Cur_Row, 2).Address).Value" with whichever column number the account number appears in. You can also add code to rename the sheets and add sheets if they don't already exist...shouldn't be too hard but if you need help let me know.